# It is possible to edit the RDP file in client side to set a specific url being launch?

Tags: rdp, remoteapp

Would like to ask, can we configure a RDP file in the client side to launch a specific url?

I already have a RDP file that will launch IE in the server. I would like a specific url being launch together with the IE.

I notice,the url can be added as a commandline argument in the properties of the RemoteApp.

But,it is possible for us to set the url in RDP file in the client side ? (The file can be opened as notepad correct? Can we edit there?)
Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1):

RDP files are plain text.  As far as I know, the full RDP file format is not documented, but as you noticed, it is rather easy to read.

The command line arguments are passed via the `remoteapplicationcmdline:s:` parameter.

If you change the file, you will get certificate errors unless you [re-sign it with `rdpsign`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/01/05/why-you-should-sign-rdp-files-and-how-to-script-the-signing.aspx).